# Arrayformula for simple addition enters random date and time

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

This extremely simple formula adds "03/01/1900 00:00:00" to one of the cells it's supposed to do show a result. Every other cell behaves normally. There is nothing but numbers in the cells it's calculating from. Seems straightforward, what's going on?

```
=ArrayFormula(D6:D + A6:A)
```

Answer (score 0):

basically it is alright. you are just supposed to fix the formatting. select the cell that is out of place and in **Format** choose **Number** instead of **Automatic** or **Date time**

[image: 0]